# How to upload Laravel 5 project to live web server

Tags: laravel-5

I believe it is much the same as a Laravel 4 upload.

I have my setup as follows, is this correct?

Is the only file I need to amend the `index.php` file which in my case is in the `techjobs` folder? I have amended this file to suit the directory structure. Are there any other files that need to change?

[image]

**index.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
 */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels nice to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../../techjobs-laravel-base/bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../techjobs-laravel-base/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can simply call the run method,
| which will execute the request and send the response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel');

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have too many steps back in your folders with ../ . Please try using below instead

```
require __DIR__.'/../techjobs-laravel-base/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

and

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../techjobs-laravel-base/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: Hmm its quite strange it only works when I use the two steps like I originally had e.g `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../techjobs-laravel-base/bootstrap/app.php';`